# Проверка чекбокса

Tags: jquery

Добрый день, всем!
Помогите реализовать:
есть кнопка "Продолжить" в виде картинки,
нужен чекбокс "я принимаю условия"

---

задача в том, что бы при нажатии на кнопку "Продолжить" проверялось отмечен ли четбокс,
если не отмечен, должно выдавать сообщение "Вы должны принять условия", и только после отметки чекбокса можно было нажимать на кнопку "Продолжить"

Пожалуйста помогите кто может, к моему стыду я  вообще не могу разобраться....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Dg2Zm/1/

Comment: Спасибо, Олег